# Book of Abstracts?

Tags: publications, phd, conference, social-science

So the conference that I am going to present a paper is going to publish a book of abstracts. Is this considered the proceedings of the conference? Or can I still grab my paper and send to a peer reviewed publication?

My field is management / social sciences.

Comment: Please add the field you are in. In chemistry for example an entry in a book of abstract or proceedings is basically worthless and it's completely normal to publish a much more elaborate version of the topic in a peer reviwed journal.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, my field is management / social sciences. So, if I have an entry in the book of abstracts, it is still ok (there is no conflict) by trying to have it published in a peer reviewed journal?

Comment: In Social Sciences, conference "papers" are more like "talks" and are less like "publications". You'd be mad to do the work of getting a talk together and not publish it elsewhere. No conflict whatsoever, what you propose is the normal pathway.

Answer (score 2):

You can still send it to a peer reviewed publication, and should. Conferences in my field (planning) are often used as a mechanism to obtain feedback on a draft paper. I'm aware of no example where 'conference proceedings' count against re-publication. My whole department submits papers for presentation to the Transportation Research Board (TRB), which then creates a compedium of the whole paper, and distributes it by CD. This is not considered publication, and most/many of the papers submitted to TRB are then revamped and published elsewhere. (TRB does cream off a limited number of papers to be published, formally, in the Transportation Research Record).

Answer (score 1):

If you read the rules of the journals, you will see that there is actually a generally accepted rule. That rule is:

**Your submitted journal paper should include at least 25% new material from the conference paper**

So, you should not simply republish the same paper, rather you should add something to it.

The logic goes like this: You have a well thought out idea. You write it up and present it at a conference. During the conference, you get a discussion going about your paper and workout some details that you might not have considered originally. Then you go back, add (or clarify) a little bit (25%) and then publish it as a journal article.

This is extremely common in business management.

Answer (score 0):

Someone from your specific field should confirm this, but in general, submitting to a journal should not be a problem.
However, do not use the same title, so that indexing/search issues don't crop up later. Similarly, you may like to modify the abstract a bit so that the two are not identical (which they shouldn't be anyway, the journal paper would typically be an extended/more detailed study).

Comment: There should be no trouble with exactly the same title and abstract if the poster wants. There are no indexing issues as the paper is not yet published.

Answer (score 0):

Social Scientist here.

Presenting at a Social Sciences conference rarely counts as publishing a paper, and when it does, you'll know, as you'll have gone through peer review at that point. This usually happens after the conference and results in an edited volume (so, a book) or a journal special issue. "Conference proceedings" are rare in Social Sciences.

The conference book of abstracts is NOT the conference proceedings, it is just a guide for people who are attending the conference. Your paper is unpublished and you can submit it for publication wherever you like.